# Can stat_summary separate groups by color on the x-axis, like geom_boxplot does?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 in R to visualize the interactions of a few different factors. So far, this does exactly what I want it to:

```
ggplot(dta_trim, aes(x=Treatment, y=Result, fill=Gender)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

In other words, it divides the data on the x-axis first by Treatment, and then by Gender, and displays the Result on the y-axis.

However, if I use any geometry other than `geom_boxplot`, it no longer divides by Gender. For example:

```
  ... +
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width = .1), alpha=.15, size=2) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.3)
```

[image: box plot not dividing by gender]

More specifically, it does seem to divide the data by Gender, but then doesn't separate them on the x-axis. (You can see the means of the male and female groups plotted separately, but one right above the other.)

How can I make these other geometries separate by Gender on the x-axis, like `geom_boxplot` does? I'd thought that setting the position function to `position_dodge` would do the trick, but it doesn't separate them like I'd hoped.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It looks like you are trying to use geoms that do not also use `fill=` so you will need to set `group=` in the `aes()` as well for those to work.

Comment: @MrFlick I'll see about putting some sample data in the example. Unfortunately, setting `group` doesn't seem to help; the mean is already grouping based on both Gender and Treatment, it's just not separating them on the x-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contrast to `geom_boxplot` which use `position_dodge` by default, a `geom_point` or `geom_errorbar` use `position="identity"`. Hence, if you want to dodge the others layers as well you have to tell `ggplo2` to do so by setting `position  = position_dodge(width = .75)` for these layers too, except for your jittered points for which you have to use `position_jitterdodge`.

Using some fake example data based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dta_trim <- mtcars |>
  dplyr::select(
    Treatment = cyl,
    Result = mpg,
    Gender = am
  ) |>
  dplyr::mutate(Treatment = factor(Treatment), Gender = factor(Gender))

ggplot(dta_trim, aes(x = Treatment, y = Result, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(
    position = position_jitterdodge(
      dodge.width = 0.75, jitter.width = .1
    ),
    alpha = .15, size = 2
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = mean, geom = "point",
    position = position_dodge(width = .75)
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.3,
    position = position_dodge(width = .75)
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://psyteachr.github.io/introdataviz/representing-summary-statistics.html#grouped-violin-boxplots

If you have a look at the above link you'll see how they did it. Essentially, you need to specify position = position_dodge(width = 0.6) or whatever width you choose for each element (boxplot, geom_point, stat_summary). This will ensure that each element gets aligned properly. For the geom_point(position = position_jitter(...)), you can replace it with position_jitterdodge(...)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).